# Is there a way to set a variable inside Nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set a environmental variable for our application inside Nginx to be variable due to some monitoring needs to have the hostname to be unique per instance. Is this possible? For instance, I want to set the hostname to be hostname-$timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare environment variables (so nginx variables) like the following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV "dev";
    ...
}
```

This is how I set environments variables while dealing with Laravel due to the framework .env concept.